# how to enable RabbitMQ management api for RabbitMQContainer of testcontainers

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I am using RabbitMQContainer to do integration test, I have the below set up:

```
@Container
final static RabbitMQContainer rabbitMQContainer = new RabbitMQContainer(DockerImageName.parse(RABBITMQ_IMAGE))
            .withExposedPorts(5672, 15672)
            .withCommand("rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_management")
            .withUser(RABBITMQ_USERNAME, RABBITMQ_PASSWORD, ImmutableSet.of("administrator"))
            .withPermission("/", RABBITMQ_USERNAME, ".*", ".*", ".*");
```

but the container failed to start up, if I remove withCommand, it can start up but I am not able to access the management API.
any suggestion about how to set up a RabbitMQContainer with management api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `withCommand` will override the default command of the Docker image and therefore break the startup contract with the `RabbitMQContainer` implementation.

I am no RabbitMQ expert, but can you use such a config and enable `rabbitmq_management` via the plugin setter?

```
@Container
final static RabbitMQContainer rabbitMQContainer = new RabbitMQContainer(DockerImageName.parse(RABBITMQ_IMAGE))
            .withExposedPorts(5672, 15672)
            .withPluginsEnabled("rabbitmq_management")
            .withUser(RABBITMQ_USERNAME, RABBITMQ_PASSWORD, ImmutableSet.of("administrator"))
            .withPermission("/", RABBITMQ_USERNAME, ".*", ".*", ".*");
```

Comment: It should be withPluginsEnabled, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code example.